# What is the significance of Für Elise in the trailer for Morbius?

Tags: soundtrack, trailers, morbius

The trailer for the upcoming film [*Morbius*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5108870/) uses segments of Beethoven's "Für Elise" mixed in with an epic score like you'd expect from a movie based in the Marvel universe. But what is the reason? Is there some kind of symbolism or significance of that song to the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the main characters also humm the intro to "Für Elise", and only intro, I assume it have to do with the "Für Elise" creation story.
Beethoven wrote this piece for student of his that was terrible at playing piano. So that's why the beginning is easy. But later he learned that she was married/egnaged/had a boyfriend. So he made the rest of the piece so hard she couldn't play it.
So Morbius is humming the intro because things are easy. He work on the cure, he help some child. Then it get so hard he start killing people.

Comment: "Beethoven wrote this piece for student of his that was terrible at playing piano. So that's why the beginning is easy. But later he learned that she was married/egnaged/had a boyfriend. So he made the rest of the piece so hard she couldn't play it." Can you cite a reputable source for it? because as far as I know, the identity of Elise is still deputed, with some scholars believing it to be Therese Malfatti, but no proof for that exists.

Comment: @Polygnome Yeah, well, Therese was the student for which Beethoven wrote that piece. https://www.all-about-beethoven.com/beethovenmature.html

Comment: The linked page calls this a *legend* - I think precisely because they know it is just that. legend, not established fact.

Comment: I wonder why, when I google "next MCU movies", "Morbius" isn't listed as one of them. Sure okay. Marvel Studios might not be responsible for filming it as others, but it is still MCU universe.